# Localhost WordPress not working

Tags: wordpress, localhost, wamp

I was working on a local site with localhost (WAMP). Everything was working fine until I disturbed my "php.ini" file. I wanted to upload files (Images) of above 2MB so I google it and found so many solutions one of [them](http://www.wpbeginner.com/wp-tutorials/how-to-increase-the-maximum-file-upload-size-in-wordpress/) was to write some code at the end of "php.ini" file. So I followed the required steps and added the code.

During this process, I accidentally deleted all the code of "php.ini" file and I closed the code editor (cant undo my changes). Now my local site has all the required data but when I open it up there is only a blank screen visible.

Help me out. I have loads of work pending.

[image]

Comment: Have you tried reinstalling wamp? Alternatively, add the [error_display rules](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21429652/6049581) to your new php.ini file to see why you are whitescreening, and work from there.

Comment: My "php.ini" file is empty so I googled and found a file on git but that doesn't work.

https://gist.github.com/adrienne/5829683

Comment: Try to add echo"xyz"; on begining & end of config file. if both echo display then issue comes from wordpress.

Comment: what is the version of `WAMP`. what is version of `php`?

Comment: @SamvelAleqsanyan version of `wamp` is 3.0.6 and version of `PHP` is 7.0.10.

Comment: what is your machine bit? x64 or x86?

Answer (score 0):

You may find **php.ini-development**,**php.ini-production** or **php.ini.ucf-dist** files in your "php 7.*" directory. Just copy code and paste in the php.ini.

Hope this will helps you.

Answer (score 0):

I googled for the whole day yesterday and finally found a working solution for my problem "[Here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=3_iIxYuZXNc)". Downgrading the PHP worked.